# How can I include python script in a HTML file?

Tags: python, html

How do I put this python script:

```
a = ['f','d','s','a']
x = -1
scope = vars()
for i in a:
    scope['x']+=1
    print a[x]
```

inside of a html file?

Comment: Python isn't like PHP, you can't just embed it as a script in HTML.

Comment: @Rafe That makes more sense. At first I thought he meant formatting with HTML pre tags.

Comment: @chrisaycock i thought that too and answered. @ones you cant just write some python code in html and execute, there are some frameworks to use python in web-technology like django, app-engine, web2py etc. Python is not a browser scripting language like javascript.

Comment: ...and what on Earth are you trying to achieve by editing the `dict` returned by `vars()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, if you want to create an html, not necessarily display it:

```
 html_file = open('namehere.html','w')
 a = ['f','d','s','a']
 x = -1
 scope = vars()
 data = ''
 for i in a: #TIP: use a generator
     scope['x']+=1
     data += a[x]
     data += '\n'
 html_file.write(data)
 html_file.close()
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162248/why-just-one-name-could-taken/4162289#4162289

Answer (score 6):

There's now a solution to this, the solution is [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/). This is a python framework that enables you to embed python scripts in HTML. Check out the sample code below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <py-script>
      print("Hello World")
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your web server supports it, you could run it as a CGI script to output an HTML file - more information here: http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/

You would need to modify your script to ouput valid HTML, but that tutorial should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. Python isn't like PHP; I can't just do this

```
<?php
```

And be good to go.

However, if your web server has a Python interpreter (most all do, these days), you can write CGI (common gateway interface) scripts to make Python code run on your webpage.

If you're trying to generate dynamic content (like change words in HTML), Javascript or PHP is better. Python is more suited to web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps CGI is what you are looking for:

http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html

http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/cgi/

For example:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print                               # blank line, end of headers

print "<html><head></head><body><pre>"
a = ['f','d','s','a']
x = -1
scope = vars()
for i in a:
    scope['x']+=1
    print a[x]
print "</pre></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

if the script is in a server , you can run it using remote funcion call through JSON-RPC
you may refer the [JSON-RPC documentation here](http://json-rpc.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use {% %} tag in html and inside this you can write your python code.

Answer (score 0):

Surround it with a `<body>` and `<head>` tag and you're golden.

But seriously, I think what you are trying to do is print fdsa, which would would look like this:

```
<head>
<body>
fdsa
</body>
</head>
```

What you have there is not really a python script.  You might need to correct that first, and then give a little more explanation what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ones You want to run your script with an HTML file as the input sequence instead of your sample "a" variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the thing into HTML or JavaScript. It would sort of be like this:

```
<script>
var a = ['f','d','s','a']
var x = -1
//other code
</script>
```

I am not showing the rest because I am not sure how to make a repeat loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Title: PyScript</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <py-script> 
a = ['f','d','s','a']
x = -1
scope = vars()
for i in a:
    scope['x']+=1
    print (a[x])
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could provide some explanation of your answer rather than just code, it will be better. :)

Answer (score -4):

**You can't.** If you want to run script in an HTML File, try another language like JavaScript or PHP. To include javascript, type this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...
</script>
```

Or in HTML5, you don't even have to type the `type` attribute:

```
<script>
    // ...
</script>
```

To include PHP, type

```
<?php
    // ...
?>
```

Comment: This answer needs to be corrected, since it actually is possible to [embed Python code in a script tag](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/intro.html?lang=en).