# why just one name could taken

Tags: python

```
def path(request, mypath):
    mypath = request.path_info
    _listdir = os.listdir(mypath)  # ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4']
    mess = _listdir
    a = ' '
    x=0
    scope = vars()  

    for i in mess:  
        scope['x']+=1  
        a += mess[x]
        a += '\n'

    return HttpResponse(a)
```

I hope the output is like this:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
```

but why the output just like this:

```
folder1
folder1
folder1
folder1
```

any help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a list of the folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> I hope the output is like this:
>
> folder1
> folder2
> folder3
> folder4
> ```

Thus shall you have your output...

```
for i in os.listdir(mypath):
    print i
```

You can `return` the `i` in the loop with `HttpResponse` there should be no problem, do this

```
returnString = ""
for i in os.listdir(mypath):
    returnString = returnString + i + "\n"

return returnString
```

Comment: @Johnsyweb What would a more "pythonic" version of such a code be?

Answer (score 4):

There are huge swathes of unnecessary code in that function.

```
def path(request):
    return HttpResponse('\n'.join(os.listdir(request.path_info)))
```

Job done!

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars):

> **Note:** The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the corresponding symbol table are undefined.

So, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
a += mess[i]
```

instead of

```
a += mess[x]
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `mess[#]` where # has to be an index, while the `for i in` loop returns strings.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you have is unneccesary.  You just want to loop through the return values.  Not modify them, nor play around with a variable indirectly via scope.

```
def path(request, mypath):
    mypath = request.path_info
    dirs = os.listdir(mypath)  # ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4']
    a = ''

    for i in dirs:  
        a += dirs
        a += '\n'

    return HttpResponse(a)
```

Comment: Not `mess` though in the for loop, but `dirs`... `mess` is undefined.