# how to print the list in three dimensional array method

Tags: python

```
list = [["acd",2,"b"],["c",33,"d"],["e","f",4]]
```

This is my list.

i want to print like

```
acd 2  b
c   33 d
e   f  4
```

Comment: Could you show what have you tried? You must show some effor while asking in StackOverflow.

Comment: check this answer :
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161332/how-can-i-include-python-script-in-a-html-file)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "print in to website". Are you trying to insert into an existing html document? Create a new one? Do you want to make some kind of <table> layout, or just what?

Comment: yeah you said it. I just only want to print like that.But i was not able to put the title as what i want while asking question So i tried crazy :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comma to keep printed output on the same line. For example

```
# don't name a list 'list' in python
lst =  [["acd",2,"b"],["c",33,"d"],["e","f",4]]

for sub in lst:
    for item in sub:
        # for each item in the sublist, print it on a single line
        print item,
    # at the end of each sublist, print a new line
    print ''
```

To get the output exactly like your example in the question, you'll have to use conditionals to check the size of each item and adjust the amount of spaces it should have before it. But this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner :)

```
>>> print "\n".join("\t".join(map(str, item)) for item in list)
acd 2   b
c   33  d
e   f   4
```

PS: I'll echo what@samrap says: Don't use `list` as variable names.