# How execute a python code on a html page?

Tags: python, html

Let me first start out by saying I am pretty new to HTML in general and have some python programming experience from learning on my own. So my question is this, I am in the process of creating a website. What I want this website to do is have four buttons on the front page (I.E "A", "B", "C", "D") and when you click on one button it takes you page "A". In page "A" there is a button labeled "Create New". What I would like this button to do is open a word document that is a form in the HTML page that then can be modified and saved to the server.

So far what I have completed is the homepage but I am stuck on how to get the "Create NeW" button to open the word document embedded in the HTML. Does this require the button to execute a python code that displays the document? Sorry if this is a dumb question. Just look for a place to start and I can probably google the rest, just don't know what to google! Thanks

Comment: I think you want to look into web frameworks e.g. Flask, Django, Pyramid, Bottle and others. Disclosure, I'm totally biased towards Flask but not a contributor: [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) will give you a start on that framework, but there's tutorials for the others too.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would look in to web frameworks and also look at this documentation that Python has in regards to using it on the web. There is also this stackoverflow that asks a similar question so have a read of this:

[How can I include python script in a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161332/how-can-i-include-python-script-in-a-html-file)

[Python Web Servers](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html)